# React and Node application not uploading Images to Cloudinary, 404 error with no explanation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, storage, cloudinary

I am trying to upload an image to cloudinary. I am using this resource as my tutorial...

I am able to render a preview of the image onto my screen and I console log the base64 encoded url, and it works as it is supposed to. After I select my Image, I hit upload and i get a 404 error on my POST request, but there is no information as to why it is happening. There is no **BAD REQUEST under the NETWORK tab** of my dev console. No image is ever rendered to my Cloudinary.

to start, here is my **index.js** code

```
const connectDB = require('./startup/db');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const users = require('./routes/users');
const kittys = require('./routes/kittys');
const friends = require('./routes/friends');
const image = require('./routes/image');
const auth = require('./routes/auth')
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { cloudinary } = require('./utils/cloudinary');
// const createError = require('http-errors');

connectDB();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/kittys', kittys);
app.use('/api/auth', auth);
app.use('/api/friends', friends);
app.use('api/upload', image)


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');  // enables all the methods to take place
    return next();
  });


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/*',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname='/public'));
})


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port: ${port}`);
})
```

here is my **image.jsx(component)** code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Alert from './Alert.js'

export default function Upload() {
    const [fileInputState, setFileInputState] = useState('');
    const [previewSource, setPreviewSource] = useState('');
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
    const [successMsg, setSuccessMsg] = useState('');
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('');
    const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        previewFile(file);
        setSelectedFile(file);
        setFileInputState(e.target.value);
    };

    const previewFile = (file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            setPreviewSource(reader.result);
        };
    };

    const handleSubmitFile = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!selectedFile) return;
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            uploadImage(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = () => {
            console.error('AHHHHHHHH!!');
            setErrMsg('something went wrong!');
        };
    };

    const uploadImage = async (base64EncodedImage) => {
        console.log(base64EncodedImage)
        try {
            await fetch('image/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ data: base64EncodedImage }),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            });
            setFileInputState('');
            setPreviewSource('');
            setSuccessMsg('Image uploaded successfully');
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            setErrMsg('Something went wrong!');
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {/* <h1 className="title">Upload an Image</h1> */}
            <Alert msg={errMsg} type="danger" />
            <Alert msg={successMsg} type="success" />
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmitFile} className="form">
                <input
                    id="fileInput"
                    type="file"
                    name="image"
                    onChange={handleFileInputChange}
                    value={fileInputState}
                    className="form-input"
                />
                <button className="btn" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
            {previewSource && (
                <img
                    src={previewSource}
                    alt="chosen"
                    style={{ height: '300px' }}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

here is my **image.js routes**:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { cloudinary } = require('../utils/cloudinary');


router.get('/api/images', async (req, res) => {
  const { resources } = await cloudinary.search
      .expression('folder:dev_setups')
      .sort_by('public_id', 'desc')
      .max_results(30)
      .execute();

  const publicIds = resources.map((file) => file.public_id);
  res.send(publicIds);
});

router.post('api/upload', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const fileStr = req.body.data;
      const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileStr, {
          upload_preset: 'dev_setups',
      });
      console.log(uploadResponse);
      res.json({ msg: 'yaya' });
  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ err: 'Something went wrong' });
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

here is my **Cloudinary** file info:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

module.exports = { cloudinary };
```

Here is my **App.js** file :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, Form, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Route, Router, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import {useCookies} from 'react-cookie';
import './App.css';
import LandingPage from './components/profile/LandingPage';
import ProfilePage from './components/profile/ProfilePage';
import Homepage from './components/profile/Homepage';
import AddCat from './components/cats/AddCat';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/profile/ProtectedRoute';
import DisplayCats from './components/cats/DisplayCats';
import MyMap from './components/map/MapContainer';
import MyImage from './components/image';
// import AddFriend from './components/AddFriend' const url =
// 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/djcngbd59/image/upload'; const preset =
// 'atmhk5x9'

const App = () => {

    const cookieName = 'straytracker';
    const [cookies,
        setCookie,
        removeCookie] = useCookies([cookieName]);

    const history = useHistory();

    let userInfo = false;

    function isEmpty(obj) {
        return Object
            .keys(obj)
            .length === 0;
    }

    if (!isEmpty(cookies)) {
        try {
            // jwtDecode just grabs the token. It does not validate the token. userInfo will
            // hold the user info in an object. If no jwt found, userInfo will hold the
            // false value.
            userInfo = cookies.straytracker;
        } catch {
            //if token is not found, send user to landing page.
            history.push("/");
            console.log(cookies)
        }
    }

    console.log(userInfo, 'userinfo check')
    const [user,
        setUser] = useState(userInfo);

    const handleLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            userInfo = cookies.straytracker;
            setUser(userInfo);

            history.push("/home");
            window
                .location
                .reload(false);
            alert('You have successfully logged in')
        } catch {
            alert('No token found')
            history.push("/");
        }
    }

    const handleLogout = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setUser(false);
        window
            .location
            .reload(false);
        removeCookie(cookieName, {path: '/'});
    }

    const setCookieApp = (jwt) => {
        // let d = new Date();
        setCookie(cookieName, jwt)
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">

                <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="/home">Stray Tracker</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="mr-auto">
                            <Nav.Link href="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/map">View Map</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/report">Add Cat</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/profile">Profile</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/upload">Upload Image</Nav.Link>
                            <NavDropdown title="More" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="/AddFriend">Add Friend</NavDropdown.Item>
                                {/* <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item> */}
                                <NavDropdown.Divider/> {/* <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item> */}
                            </NavDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={handleLogout}>
                            Logout
                        </Button>
                        <Form inline>
                            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2"/>
                            <Button variant="outlined">Search</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </header>

            <Router history={history}>
                {/* <ProtectedRoute exact path='/home' user={userInfo ? user:null} component={Homepage} handleLogout={handleLogout}/> */}
                <Route
                    exact
                    path='/'
                    handleLogin={handleLogin}
                    render={props => <LandingPage{...props}
                    user={user}
                    handleLogin={handleLogin}
                    setCookieApp={setCookieApp}/>}/>
                <ProtectedRoute
                    exact
                    path='/home'
                    user={user}
                    component={Homepage}
                    handleLogout={handleLogout}/>
                <ProtectedRoute
                    exact
                    path='/profile'
                    user={user}
                    component={ProfilePage}
                    handleLogout={handleLogout}/>
                <ProtectedRoute
                    exact
                    path='/report'
                    user={user}
                    component={AddCat}
                    handleLogout={handleLogout}/> {/* <Route
                    exact
                    path='/map'
                    user={user}
                    component={MapContainer}
                    handleLogout={handleLogout}/> */}
                <ProtectedRoute
                    exact
                    path='/cats'
                    render={props => <DisplayCats {...props} user={user}/>}/>
                <ProtectedRoute
                    exact
                    path='/upload'
                    user={user}
                    component={MyImage}
                    handleLogout={handleLogout}/>
                <Route exact path='/map' render={props => <MyMap {...props} user={user}/>}/> {/* <ProtectedRoute exact path='/AddFriend' user={user} component={AddFriend} /> */}

            </Router>

        </div>
    );
}

export default App
```

and here is my **Server package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index2.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.23.0",
    "config": "^3.3.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^4.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http-errors": "^1.8.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "joi": "^17.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.15",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you shared I see that you have a POST route defined for `api/upload`, however, the `uploadImage` call sends the request to `image/upload` which is not a defined route. Could you update the endpoint in `uploadImage` from `image/upload` to `api/upload` and test the upload again.